# How to insert new Object element in array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

```
I have this Document so structured
Process: Object
        Code: 1
        Descr: "Analyze"
DocumentToCreate: Array
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
        Type: Object
            Code:"R3"
            Desc:"CV"
        Condition: Object
            0: Object
                KeyDoc: "is not null"
            1: Object
                ReasonInsertion.Code: "03"
            2: Object
                Raw.Id: "is not null"
            3: Object
                Product.FlagDelete: false
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
```

In the Condition object in position 5(filtered by value of Type.Code "R3") I have to add a new element, to find the correct document I should filter the one with Process.Code = 1
How can I generate a script to perform this update?

**UPDATE**
This the data in the document

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "728b678c11f25b32b1f59d8b"
    },
    "Process": {
        "Code": 1,
        "Desc": "Analyze"
    },
    "DocumentToCreate": [
        {
            "Type": {
                "Code": "19",
                "Desc": "Receipt"
            }
        },
        {
            "Type": {
                "Code": "20",
                "Desc": "Invoice"
            }
        },
        {
            "Type": {
                "Code": "PH",
                "Desc": "Photo"
            }
        },
        {
            "Type": {
                "Code": "11",
                "Desc": "Technical documentation"
            },
            "Condition": [
                {
                    "Key": "is not null"
                },
                {
                    "Raw.Id": "04"
                },
                {
                    "ReasonInsertion.Code": "99"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": {
                "Code": "13",
                "Desc": "Booking quote"
            },
            "Condition": [
                {
                    "Key": "is not null"
                },
                {
                    "Raw.Id": "01"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": {
                "Code": "R3",
                "Desc": "CV"
            },
            "Condition": [
                {
                    "Key": "is not null"
                },
                {
                    "ReasonInsertion.Code": "00"
                },
                {
                    "Raw.Id": "is not null"
                },
                {
                    "Product.FlagDelete": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": {
                "Code": "50",
                "Desc": "Products for sale"
            },
            "Condition": [
                {
                    "Key": "is not null"
                },
                {
                    "People.Code": "Seller"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": {
                "Code": "C3",
                "Desc": "General conditions of sale used"
            },
            "Condition": [
                {
                    "Key": "is not null"
                },
                {
                    "Discount.Code": "11"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": {
                "Code": "A4",
                "Desc": "Discounted goods"
            },
            "Condition": [
                {
                    "Object.Product.Book.Type": "K,A"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": {
                "Code": "AC",
                "Desc": "Annex Clauses"
            },
            "Condition": [
                {
                    "Raw.Id": "01"
                },
                {
                    "Object.Position": "02"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": {
                "Code": "W3",
                "Desc": "Goods on loan"
            },
            "Condition": [
                {
                    "Key": "is not null"
                },
                {
                    "People.Code": "Rent"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": {
                "Code": "R6",
                "Desc": "Return of Goods"
            },
            "Condition": [
                {
                    "Raw.Id": "04"
                },
                {
                    "ReasonInsertion.Code": "OUT"
                },
                {
                    "Object.Product.Book.IsSelled": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to add as mentioned above a new element into object "Condition" in:

```
"Type": {
                "Code": "R3",
                "Desc": "CV"
            },
            "Condition": [
                {
                    "Key": "is not null"
                },
                {
                    "ReasonInsertion.Code": "00"
                },
                {
                    "Raw.Id": "is not null"
                },
                {
                    "Product.FlagDelete": false
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Can you add a sample document with proper key names? It looks simple update command would work

Comment: I have update my answer with sample